# Redirect www.newkannada.com/post/ to www.newkannada.com/post.html wordpress htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to remove year and month and redirect my old post from google search from
https://www.newkannada.com/2014/12/mandya-star-2015-kannada-movie-mp3.html to https://www.newkannada.com/mandya-star-2015-kannada-movie-mp3.html
In wordpress using htaccess..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.html [L,R=301]
```